# Should I use mean, standard deviation, or coefficient of variation in cross-validation?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, cross-validation

I'm using cross-validation and calculating the AUCs, and then calculating the mean, the standard deviation(SD), and taking the same standard deviation and dividing it by the same mean to calculate the coefficient of variation.

Now I want to know how good my model is, should I use the mean, the SD, or the coefficient of variation?

I know that when comparing different models, we will take the higher mean, the lower SD, or the lower coefficient of variation, but how to tell if the model is performing good in general? Is there a general good value for the mean of the AUCs, the SD, and the coefficient of variation? And is everything I said correct or not?

An example would be:

- mean = 0.93
- SD = 0.1
- coefficient of variation = 0.11

Is the model doing good or bad? Does everything make sense in my question?